# devtools::check() creating warning that only contains NULL

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm currently doing some work on a package, and calling `devtools::check()` is producing the following warning:

```r
❯ checking Rd files ... WARNING
  NULL
```

However, when manually inspecting each of the `.Rd` files created by `devtools::document()` and re-reading the documentation, I don't see why this warning is appearing. I know it's only a warning and doesn't impact the functionality of the package, but I can't figure out where this is coming from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This `rig`-related bug has been fixed with version `0.5.2`, see [r-lib/rcmdcheck#184](https://github.com/r-lib/rcmdcheck/issues/184#issuecomment-1252099608) on GitHub. @rossdrucker9 I am well aware that you already know about this.. just want to write it down for future generations that end up here first (like I did).